# Is there any for loop in Firebase Security Rules for RealTime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I walked through a lot of websites and documentation containing info about security rules and how to deploy them. But one thing I couldn't find was the "for loop" inside security rules.
So, I have this case that, there are n questions with z options and n is stored in another variable n in database but to make sure the answer key is not tampered or if anything goes wrong it must be validated.

> {othervalue:"x", answer:[1,2,3,4,5]}

I want to validate that it has n values as well as all values are less than z how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to loop over data in Firebase's security rules, as that would lead to potentially unbounded run time.

The typical solution is to change your data model to allow the security rule to perform a direct lookup, or to perform the validation of your data at a different moment.

For example: to validate that the answers are less than a certain value, you can validate the individual values:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "answer": {
      "$answer": {
        ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() < 42"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

A trick that I recently thought of to validate the length of an array would be to check for the specific indexes, and disallow anything else:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "answer": {
      "0": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() < 42" }, 
      "1": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() < 42" && newData.parent().child('0').exists() }, 
      "2": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() < 42" && newData.parent().child('1').exists() }, 
      "3": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() < 42" && newData.parent().child('2').exists() }, 
      "4": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() < 42" && newData.parent().child('3').exists() }, 
      "$other": { ".validate": false }
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: I haven't tested these rules in practice yet, so your mileage may vary.*

So in these last rules, we allow an array of 5 elements (as in your example), by validating that only those specific keys exist (and that they are sequential).

Comment: The no. of index is not defined so?

Comment: In that case I don't think there's a way to enforce it through security rules, and you'll have to look at another approach (such as running trusted code on a server or in Cloud Functions).